locus of points seeing two segments with equal angles
Given the two segments $AB$ and $BC$ I would like to characterize the set of points in the plane:
$$
\{P\colon \widehat{APB}=\widehat{BPC}\}.
$$
Looking at the picture obtained with geogebra looks like a parabola:


I constructed the locus with GeoGebra, and it isn't a conic but a higher degree curve. A part of the locus is formed by line $AC$ minus segment $AC$.

It might be a bit more complicated that that. In the case here $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with the vertex at $B$, I believe (no concrete proof) that the answer is 1/ perpendicular bisector of $AC$, union 2/ arc of $AC$  in the circumcircle $ABC$, union 3/ line $AC$ minus line segment $AC$.

I'll find the equation of the curve in the case $AB\perp AC$. The general case can be treated in an analogous way but the algebra is harder.
We can set in this case:
$$
A=(0, 2a),\quad B=(0,0),\quad C=(2c, 0).
$$
Let's then take a point $D=(c,h)$ on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$. All points on the arc $BDC$ subtend the same angle $\alpha=2\arctan|c/h|$ at $BC$. If we then construct point $E=(ha/c,a)$, all points on the arc $BEA$ subtend the same angle $\alpha$ at $AB$. The locus we want to find is formed by the intersections of those arcs as parameter $h$ varies.
It is easy to check that circles $BDC$ and $BEA$ have equations:
$$
x^2 + y^2 - 2 c x + c \left({c\over h} - {h\over c}\right) y = 0\\
x^2 + y^2 - 2 a y + a \left({c\over h} - {h\over c}\right) x=0
$$
Eliminating $h$ gives the cartesian equation of the locus:
$$
(a x - c y) (x^2+y^2) -2 a c (x^2 - y^2) =0.
$$
This is the equation of a cubic (blue in figure below). In addition line $AC$ also belongs to le locus (with the exception of segment $AC$) but is not contained in the cubic (see however edit below).
EDIT.
As observed in a comment, one should also consider circle $BE'A$, where $E'=(-ha/c,a)$, because arc $BE'A$ also subtends angle $\alpha$ at $AB$. The equation of this circle is
$$
x^2 + y^2 - 2 a y - a \left({c\over h} - {h\over c}\right) x=0
$$
and after eliminating $h$ a term $x^2+y^2$ factors out of the resulting cubic, leaving a linear term:
$$
2ac-ax-cy=0,
$$
which is just the equation of line $AC$.

A closer inspection shows that some portions of those curves are not really a part of the locus, because we have found the intersections of the full circles instead of the arcs. We must discard that part of the line $AC$ lying in the first quadrant, as well as those parts of the cubic lying in the second and fourth quadrant.

Re the lost  locus, part of the issue is that you also need to consider the point $E' = (-ha/c, a)$, and take  intersection of the circumcircles of $BAE'$ and $BDC$. That gives you the ray from $A$.

@CalvinLin You are right, of course. I edited my answer.

Because you're working with arcs and not complete circles, you do have to verify the the points lie on the arcs, as opposed to just satisfying the equation.  EG We do not want the line segment $AC$, other than the point of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$ which is given by your cubic.  $\quad$ This would explain why we only take rays from A and C: The arc $BE'C$ intersects $ADB$ at the ray from $C$. Likewise, the arc $BEC$ intersects $AD'B$ at the ray from $A$.  $\quad$ Furthermore, the arcs $AD'B$ and $BE'C$ can intersect each other, where $PB$ is the angle bisector of $\angle APC$.

@CalvinLin Yes, that's why I added that last comment but hadn't time to give a full explanation.

Summary
The locus of $P$ has a very simple geometric description. If one invert it with respect to circles centered at $B$, its image is part of a hyperbola whose axes are parallel/perpendicular to the angular bisector at $B$.

Choose a coordinate system such that $B$ is origin and the incenter $I$ of $\triangle ABC$ lies on positive $x$-axis.
Flip, scale and relabel vertices if needed, we can assume $A$ and $C$ lie on the $1^{st}$ and $4^{th}$ quadrants respectively and $c = |AB| \le |BC| = a$ with $ac = 1$.
Identify Eucliean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. We will abuse notation and use same symbol to denote a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and corresponding complex number in $\mathbb{C}$.
For any point $P$ differs from $A,B,C$, the condition $\widehat{APB}=\widehat{BPC}$, when interpreted as equality among signed angles, is equivalent to the existence of a positive $\lambda$ such that:
$$\frac{A-P}{B-P} = \lambda \frac{B-P}{C-P}\quad\iff\quad
\left(\frac{A}{P} - 1\right)\left(\frac{C}{P} - 1\right) = \lambda$$
For any point $X$, let $\tilde{X} = \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ be its image under inversion with respect to the unit circle centered at  $B$. Let $M = \frac12(A + C)$ be mid-point of segment $AC$. It is easy to see its conjugate $\bar{M}$ is mid-point of segment $\tilde{A}\tilde{C}$.
Since $I \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $ac = 1$. We can rewrite RHS of last equation as
$$(\tilde{P} - \tilde{A})(\tilde{P} - \tilde{C}) = \lambda
\iff \tilde{P}^2 - 2\bar{M}\tilde{P} + 1 = \lambda
\tag{*1}$$
This implies

$\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{C}$ lies on the boundary of locus of $\tilde{P}$.
The locus of $\tilde{P}$ is invariant under reflection $\tilde{P} \mapsto 2\bar{M} - \tilde{P}$.

Let $\tilde{P} = u + vi$ and $\bar{M} =  m+ ni$. In terms of $u,v,m,n$, the real/imaginary part of $(*1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
(u-2m)u - (v-2n)v + 1 &= \lambda\\
(u-m)(v-n) &= mn
\end{align}$$
The $2^{nd}$ equation tell us $\tilde{P}$ lies on an axes-aligned hyperbola passing through origin.
Since $c \le a$, it is easy to see $m > 0$ and $n \ge 0$. So one branch of this hyperbola lies completely within $1^{st}$ quadrant.
It is easy to see $\tilde{A}$ belongs to this branch and if one start from $\tilde{A}$ and move towards $+\infty + ni$, the $\lambda$ in $1^{st}$ increases. This means the part of this branch between $\tilde{A}$ and $+\infty + ni$ belongs to locus of $\tilde{P}$.
For the other branch of this hyperbola. It is easy to see $\tilde{C}$ in $4^{th}$ quadrant lie on it. Furthermore, if one start from $\tilde{C}$ and move towards $-\infty+ni$, $\lambda$ in $1^{st}$ equation increases again. This means
the part of this branch between $\tilde{C}$ and $-\infty+ni$ is the remaining
locus of $\tilde{P}$.
Notice origin corresponds to $\lambda = 1$ and belongs to the $2^{nd}$ branch.
We can decompose locus of $\tilde{P}$ into 3 pieces

the branch at $1^{st}$ quadrant joining $\tilde{A}$ to $+\infty+ni$.
the portion of $2^{nd}$ branch in $4^{th}$ quadrant joining $\tilde{C}$ to $0$.
the portion of $2^{nd}$ branch in $2^{nd}$ quadrant joining $0$ to $-\infty + ni$.

Apply an inverse circle inversion, we find the locus of $P$ falls into 3 pieces.

a curve at $1^{st}$ quadrant joining $A$ to $B$.
a curve at $4^{th}$ quadrant joining $C$ to $M(+\infty - iK)$ where $K = \frac{mn}{(m^2+n^2)^2}$.
a curve at $2^{nd}$ quadrant joining $B$ to $M(-\infty - iK)$.

Furthermore, the last two curves share a common asymptote parallel to segment $BM$.
For the other interpretation of the condition as equality between unsigned angles. One need to look for points that satisfy
$$\frac{A-P}{B-P} = \lambda \frac{C-P}{B-P}\quad\text{for some}\quad\lambda > 0$$
It is clear $\lambda \ne 1$, we can rewrite this equation as
$$P = \frac{1}{1-\lambda} A + \frac{-\lambda}{1-\lambda} B$$
Since the coefficients in front of $A,B$ sum to $1$, $P$ lies on the line joining $A, B$. Since the coefficients have opposite sign, $P$ need to lie outside the segment joining $A, B$. The end result is the "extra" locus of this
interpretation are two rays start at $A$ and $B$ pointing away from each other.

Elegant exposition!

Very interesting approach !

Calling
$$
\cases{
p_a = (x_a,y_a)\\
p_b = (x_b,y_b)\\
p_c = (x_c,y_c)\\
p = (x,y)
}
$$
we have
$$
\cases{
(p_a-p)\cdot(p_b-p) = |p_a-p||p_b-p|\cos \alpha\\
(p_b-p)\cdot(p_c-p) = |p_b-p||p_b-p|\cos \beta\\
}
$$
so choosing $\alpha = \beta$ implies
$$
\frac{(p_a-p)\cdot(p_b-p)}{|p_a-p||p_b-p|} = \frac{(p_b-p)\cdot(p_c-p)}{|p_b-p||p_c-p|}
$$
How many line asymptotes has this curve?
Follows a plot showing in dashed blue the locus, for a case with
$$
\cases{
p_a = (1,2)\\
p_b = (0,0)\\
p_c = (2,-1/2)}
$$


What a nice plot!

Yet another approach that yields a more complicated answer by taking an alternate interpretation of the OP's problem.
In the discussion below we will use the complex-variable identity
(1) $Arg( w_1/w_2)= Arg w_1 - Arg w_2$
Using complex notation for the various points, we can express the two counter-clockwise oriented angles depicted by the OP as
(2.1 ) $\angle APB= Arg(w_1)$ where $w_1= \frac{A-P}{ B-P}$ and likewise
(2.2) $\angle BPC= Arg(w_2)$ where $w_2= \frac{B-P}{ C-P}$
Then by (1), the vanishing of the difference of these two angles can be expressed in consolidated form as $Arg( W)=0$
where $W= w_1/w_2$.   Explicitly
(3) $W= f(P)= \frac{w_1}{w_2}=\frac{\frac{ A-P}{B-P}}{\frac{ B-P}{C-P}} = \frac{ (C-P)(A-P)}{(B-P)^2}$ which is a rational function in the complex variable $P$
Note that $0=Arg W$  is equivalent to the condition that $W$ lies on the positive real axis.
After a translation of the origin in the $P$ plane we may assume $B=0$. Then we see that $f(P)$ can be expressed as a quadratic function of the auxiliary variable $Z= P^{-1}$.  Explicitly,
$W= f(P(Z))= (CA) Z^2 -(A+C) Z +1$.
The inverse image of the positive real $W$ axis by the quadratic mapping $W=f(P(Z))$ provides the locus in the $Z$ plane, and then inversion under the reciprocal map transforms this $Z$-locus to the $P$ plane.
Footnote.
If instead one sets $Arg w_1= - Arg w_2$ then a much simpler solution occurs, involving only linear-fractional maps rather than quadratic maps. The solution locus is then an arc of a circle (or a line).
